# Loader not showing when making AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a JavaScript function which makes an AJAX call to return some data, the call is triggered on a select list change event.

I have tried many ways to display my loader whilst it's waiting, as it currently pauses the select list and doesn't look very good from a customer point of view.

The problem is, no matter what way I've tried to get this to show, the AJAX call completes before the loader shows.

Current Code:

```
<select name="addresslist" class="form-select" id="edit-addresslist" onchange="selectAddress(this)">
<option value="none">-- Please select an address from the list below --</option>
//there are more options but this isn't important here       
</select>
```

JS File

```
function selectAddress(data) {
var loader = document.getElementbyId('overlay-loader');
var selectedAddress = data.value;
var uprn = selectedAddress.split(',')[1];

loader.style.display = "block";

$.ajax({
    url: '~/collectiondates',
    async: false,
    data: {
        uprn: uprn
    },

    success: function (data) {

        result = data;
}
```

This is one of the ways I have tried, I have also tried calling a separate function on the "onchange" event, a separate function within selectAddress and another function which shows the loader then calls "selectAddress" but nothing works, the AJAX function is always completed first and then shows the loader (when it's no longer needed).

The rest of the code does exactly as expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should use deferred promises including done,fail and always with your ajax call and even a settimeout if the request is that fast check the example I made in this  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xhke5pt/1/), also here is a syntax example:

```
$( function() {
  function AjaxCall(rID,rStatus,rComment){
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'request.php',
      data: {
        id: rID,
        requisitionStatus: rStatus,
        comment: rComment    
      },
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#requisitionStatusDialog").dialog('close');
        $('#ajax_loader_my').show();
      }
    })
  }


  $( "#requisitionStatusDialog" ).dialog();

  $("#yourbuttonInputId").on('click',function(event) {
    AjaxCall().done(function(data,response){
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      if (obj.status == "success") {
        alert('whe are on done!');
      }
    }).fail(function(data,response){
      $("#updateDialog").dialog(' close');
    }).always(function(data){
      if(confirm('You have finished the request.  Click OK if you wish to continue ,click Cancel to reload the page.'))
      {
        $('#ajax_loader_my').hide();
        $("#requisitionStatusDialog").dialog('open');
      }else{
        location.reload();
      }

    });
  });
} );
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing the AJAX code inside a setTimeout function, in case the backend is working too fast.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // put here your AJAX
}, 2000); // 2 seconds delay
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably showing later because you are not setting the css to hide after success/error is returned. If you are worried about the loader not showing before the ajax finishes, you can set a delay in the AJAX call using setTimeout function
Here is what I do.
HTML -

```
<select name="addresslist" class="form-select" id="edit-addresslist" onchange="selectAddress(this)">
<option value="none">-- Please select an address from the list below --</option>
//there are more options but this isn't important here       
</select>
```

JS/JQ -

```
function selectAddress(data) {
openloader();
var selectedAddress = data.value;
var uprn = selectedAddress.split(',')[1];

$.ajax({
    url: '~/collectiondates',
    async: false,
    data: {
        uprn: uprn
    },

    success: function (data) {
        closeloader();
        result = data;
    }
 }
 }

function openloader(){
    $("#overlay-loader").show();
}

function closeloader(){
    $("#overlay-loader").hide();
}
```